# SSIS Speed up working days calculation query

Tags: sql, performance, function, ssis

For each row in db I need to calculate number of working days between 2 days. So I created a function which takes 2 date parameters, connects to date dimension and counts number of working days between input time period. This works fine expect it's very slow since it has to do calculation for each row.

Just to compare, if I select just random columns from table (excluding cycleTime calculation) then speed is 1 million rows in few seconds.
If I include CycleTime calculation that uses sql function then speed is 15k rows per 10 seconds. In total it's around 10 minutes for 1 million rows.

Here is the query

```
SELECT 
CycleTime = 
    CASE WHEN DateStarted is not null and DateCompleted is not null
    THEN DM.dbo.ufnCalculateWorkingDays(DateStarted, DateCompleted)
    ELSE NULL 
    END
from MyTable
```

And function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnCalculateWorkingDays]
(
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @WorkingDays int;

    WITH CTE AS 
    (   
        select WorkingDay = Date 
        from DimDate
        where 
        Date between @StartDate and @EndDate
        AND IsHolidayUSA = 0
        AND IsWeekday = 1
    )

    Select @WorkingDays = COUNT(*) from CTE 

    RETURN @WorkingDays;
END
```

Is there any other approach to speed up the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?   (obviously unable to performance test since I don't have your database):

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT [Date] AS WorkingDay,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS RN
 FROM DimDate
 WHERE IsHolidayUSA = 0
 AND IsWeekday = 1
)
SELECT
 DateStarted,
 DateCompleted,
 c2.RN - c1.RN AS CycleTime
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN cte c1
 ON t.DateStarted=c1.WorkingDay
INNER JOIN cte c2
 ON t.DateCompleted=c2.WorkingDay
```

If DateStarted and DateCompleted are both covered in the same index, it ought to be pretty fast.

Comment: Could also add that as a `WorkingDayNumber` column on the Date dimension to make it even faster. Guess the only thing to watch out for is the DateStarted and DateCompleted occuring on non-working days.

Comment: True, if modifying the DimDate table is an option, that would be even better.

Comment: This is much faster, I would say fast enough so I don't need to modify DimDate. Thanks :) btw, there is comma missing iny our query, 2rd line